# Issue with customizing kernel cmdline option in Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: ubuntu, grub

Im trying to add rootdelay=60 option in grub cmdline options by editing file `/etc/default/grub` as

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rootdelay=300"` and also ran
`update-grub`
`update-initramfs -u`
however i do not observe any delay after reboot and the root filesystem mounts right away

i can see that the rootdelay=300 is present in `cat /proc/cmdline` ,is there any thing missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

rootdelay only waits until the rootfs device is available.

The kernel documentation is not very concise:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html

however, there is an answer on the Unix stackexchange that provides additional explanation:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67199/whats-the-point-of-rootwait-rootdelay